# Why can't Ruby find my Net::SCP?

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems, rake, environment

My Rake task fails with the following error:

```
plt$ rake build
rake aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- net/scp
/Users/plt/Developer/Ruby/tools/Rake/helpers/ota_generator.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/plt/Developer/Ruby/tools/Rake/configuration/ios/delivery.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/plt/Developer/Ruby/tools/Rake/configuration/ios/global_config.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/plt/Developer/Ruby/tools/Rake/ios.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/plt/Developer/iOS/project/Rakefile:10:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

The Net::SCP gem is already installed and `ruby -e "require 'net/scp'"` works fine.

The "LoadError" disappears if I add `require 'net/scp'` at the beginning of the Rakefile.

I moved `require 'net/scp'` from files to files to see were it starts to fail. Here is the result:

```
/Users/plt/Developer/iOS/project/Rakefile -> `require 'net/scp'` **OK**
/Users/plt/Developer/Ruby/tools/Rake/ios.rb -> `require 'net/scp'` **OK**
/Users/plt/Developer/Ruby/tools/Rake/configuration/ios/global_config.rb -> `require 'net/scp'` **OK**
/Users/plt/Developer/Ruby/tools/Rake/configuration/ios/delivery.rb -> `require 'net/scp'` **KO** `LoadError: cannot load such file -- net/scp`
/Users/plt/Developer/Ruby/tools/Rake/helpers/ota_generator.rb -> `require 'net/scp'` **KO** `LoadError: cannot load such file -- net/scp`
```

My Rake task launches a build tool which has many Ruby files and uses many gems, but so far only two gems are giving me a hard time: CFPropertyList and Net::SCP.

At first I thought it came from my Ruby environment, BUT I already checked and it seems fine.

```
plt$ which ruby
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby

plt$ gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.5.0
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.0.0 (2015-04-13 patchlevel 645) [universal.x86_64-darwin15]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/plt/.gem/ruby/2.0.0
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/plt/.gem/ruby/2.0.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/plt/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/plt/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /Library/Ruby/Site
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - universal-darwin-15
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/plt/.gem/ruby/2.0.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /Users/plt/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/bin
     - /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/bin
     - /bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /sbin
     - /opt/X11/bin
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the formatting help for the text edit box. When asking questions it's important to format your question so it's readable and follows the standard SO look, which helps us understand you then provide an answer. It's also important to avoid fluff and be concise; Stick to the facts, tell us clearly and concisely what is happening, and we'll try to help.

Comment: How did you install Net::SCP?

Comment: I chose to install my gem home in my home directory to avoid permissions issue with OXS El Capitan. `gem list` shows `net-scp (1.2.1)`

Comment: You should look into using rbenv or RVM. Installing the gems in your home is OK, but you'll still want to update gems bundled with the system Ruby at some point, along with upgrade to more recent Rubies. rbenv and RVM handle that very nicely.

Comment: Are you using bundler?

Comment: @FrederickCheung: Yes I installed the gem with bundler.

Comment: Is the gem in your Gemfile then - does your project require bundler/setup?

Comment: Yes the gem was listed in the project's Gemfile. I runned `bundle install` which install all the needed gems